# Resolving a null type with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Apology first, I am really beginner with the LINQ, hence the question.

I am being unable to catch values that are null form the database. I am making a LINQ to DataTable. I am checking the double type.

This is the code I have:

```
var results2 = from myRow in table.AsEnumerable()
                                       where myRow.Field<double>("Cost") == 0
                                       select myRow;
```

That Code works fine if a value is zero. How Do I make it check for null as well?

Another question is also related to this issue:

I have this code:

```
var results = from myRow in table.AsEnumerable()
                                       where myRow.Field<string>("Name") == "test"
                                       select myRow;
```

And that works just fine if the value is test. How do I check if the "Name" column is empty/null??

Comment: `myRow.Field<double?>("Cost") == null`?

Comment: Why do you use `.AsEnumerable()`? Are you sure this is Linq to SQL? Why not use a typed data context?

Comment: I am running this LINQ against the DataTable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `OR` condition with the `||` operator.

For your nullable double case, you will need to check if it has a value AND is the value you expect, in addition to checking for null.

```
var results2 = from myRow in table.AsEnumerable()
               where (
                   myRow.Field<double?>("Cost").HasValue &&
                   myRow.Field<double?>("Cost").Value == 0)
               || !myRow.Field<double?>("Cost").HasValue
               select myRow;


var results = from myRow in table.AsEnumerable()
              where myRow.Field<string>("Name") == "test" ||
                    myRow.Field<string>("Name") == null
              select myRow;
```